# Get around Disallowed MIME Type when importing json in Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, mime-types

I am working on my first Vue.js app.

I have an external dataset in `data.json` in my main directory and I would like to import the data.

```js
import ECUDATA_JSON from './data.json'
```

gives me

```
Loading module from “http://localhost/myproject/data.json” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“application/json”)
```

How do I get around that?

What concept is at play here that I don't understand?

(Running on my local Apache server under Linux.)